# UICollectionView first cell not aligned properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my app, I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableView that is showing cells to select a day.

I had a weird issue where sometimes, the cells would be centered correctly, and sometimes it wouldn't, to the point where part of the first cell is cut off in the view.

Normal
[image]

Not Aligned
[image]

What is going on? I've adjusted the UIEdgeInsets, but it doesn't seem to make an effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that my issue was fixed when I removed this line of code for the UICollectionViewFlowLayout of the UICollectionView

For a defined

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
```

Remove this

```
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```